# Smooth rendering

Tags: modeling, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

Attached is my attempt at a globe. You will see that the rendered image is not sharp and smooth at the edges. I have highlighted a few of these areas. How do I render images that are sleek and smooth.[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you upload a higher resolution? You may just need to add a subdivision surface modifier

Comment: Is this the actual rendered image or a screenshot from an image viewer? Some image viewers use no interpolation if the image is scaled down which can lead to these artifacts.

Comment: Added another image.

Comment: is your resolution set at 100%?

Comment: From the first screenshot it seemed to me like lack of antialiasing. With second I'm not sure what is the main problem

Comment: @cegaton, bumping up the resolution worked. If you can add it as answer, I will accept it. Thx!